# Straining the command line through functions declared in one's .bashrc

Tags: bash

I have a large number of `bash` functions in several files that get sourced within my `.bashrc`.

Would like to be able to have some switching mechanism to enable or disable the use of specific functionality (the use of specific function).  What can I do?

For instance, consider an Ubuntu System.  I have a file that contains a number of functions (with additional help and documentation functions in there as well).  The file provides functionality for migrating data or doing backups.

Here are the function names

```
shuttle
shuttle-usage
shuttle-help

shuttle-boost
shuttle-boost-usage
shuttle-boost-help
```

In my `.bashrc`, I have the sourcing command that makes the shuttle functionality available for users.

```
shuttle-export ()
 {
  trkrc="${HOME}/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/opcon/"

  source ${trkrc}/shuttle.rc
 }
```

Whilst this allows users to use the shuttle functionality in the command line, there is not possibility to disable the function from use, and be enable them again when required for use.

My concern is this.  As I introduce more and more command line tools, could I actually strain the command line too much? How can one figure that out? In what ways can one burden the command line? With too much memory consumption for instance?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. First, explain what you want to achieve, what would "disable" look like in this context? Why not just not run the functions if you don't want to? Or are they run automatically? We need to understand what you are trying to do in order to help. Also, please add your operating system so we know what environment you are working on.

Comment: Why would you disable this? Simply do not execute `shuttle-export` and you won't have the functions. Then, when you want them, run your `shuttle-export` function and that will "enable" the rest. Don't you already have exactly what you want? You could write a function that unsets each function you don't want (e.g. `unset shuttle-usage`), but why? If you don't want a function, don't run it. Or open a new shell where the functions will no longer be active. What am I missing here?

Comment: As I introduce more and more command line tools, could I actually strain the command line too much?  How can one figure that out?  In what ways can one burden the command line?  With too much memory consumption for instance?

Comment: OK, if that is what you're worried about, that needs to be mentioned in the question. But function definitions don't add much overhead, nothing that is relevant in modern systems unless you are working in a very limited environment like an embedded system or something like that. If you just define the function and don't call it, its effect is negligible. And unsetting the function will make no real difference either. At worst, if your .bashrc becomes very, very large you might start seeing a slight delay when you open a new terminal.

Comment: Does it mean that if a function is not ever called in the command line, the internal variables are not instantiated by the shell?

Comment: Do all these functions need to be shell functions? Those that don't you can convert to scripts. Place the scripts in some custom `bin/`, add this `bin` to your `PATH`. Then there's nothing to initialize. Your shell won't know about any of the scripts until you want to run one and the shell uses `$PATH` to find it.

Comment: I included them in the `.bashrc` because I want them to be conveniently available to users when they need them without having them to input specific paths every time.

Comment: "without having them to input specific paths" – You do know how `PATH` works, right? Right?

Comment: I just add the path to the bash file. Then users call commands simply with `shuttle`, `shuttle-boost`, etc.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on several of the comments. If you have added these functions in, for instance, `/etc/profile.d/local_aliases.sh` to make them available to all users, then the additional memory required for defining each alias is trivial. Local variables defined within each alias is local to the alias and does not add to the shell's memory (although this would also be trivial). You will not "burden" the command line other than giving users more commands to remember. Don't worry about memory consumption.